# CPU usage becomes 0 as soon as I attach the process to windbg

Tags: c#, service, windbg, windows-server-2008-r2, cpu-usage

I was given a memory dump to analyze for High CPU usage of a service which is running on Windows 2008 R2 (Client machine). 
The dump was taken using task manager.

I tried using the symbols which were available with us on the dump which was provided to me (**The dump was taken using task manager**), but no success. 
Later, I found that the dump taken from task manager was not working hence I took the dump of the service **on my system** using Windbg. I was able to load the symbols.

But, I was in need of the dump files from client machine. When I tried to take the dump of the service when it was consuming around 85% of CPU by attaching it to **Windbg**, to my surprise the CPU consumption suddenly dropped to 0%.

Obviously I need the dump from the client machine to analyze whats happening and why the service is consuming 85% of CPU.

Not getting how to take the dump using Windbg, as soon as I attach the service by pressing F6, the CPU consumption drops to 0%.

Answer (score 6):

When you attach with windbg all the threads are suspended in your service until you issue the `g` command. That's why your service's CPU consumption goes to zero. But that's OK because you have a snapshot of what all your threads were doing when CPU consumption *was* at 85%. The `~*kb` command will show you that. Then issue `g`, notice that CPU consumption goes back up. When it's high enough, break in (Debug | Break) and then run `~*kb` again to see what the threads were doing. Repeat multiple times and you should see a pattern. Also, use `!runaway` each time to easily see the busiest threads.

Comment: snapshot doesn't show the past, this is why ETW/xperf is the much better way to diag CPU usage

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using dumps, use ETW to capture a trace of the CPU usage. ETW traces contain a sum of the calls and not snapshots like you have in dumps. To capture a trace, install the [Windows Performance Toolkit from the Windows SDK](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4847.install-the-windows-performance-toolkit-wpt.aspx), open a [command prompt as admin](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/how-do-i-run-an-application-once-with-a-full-administrator-access-token) and run this to capture the CPU usage:

> xperf -on latency -stackwalk profile -buffersize 2048 -MaxFile 2048
>   -FileMode Circular && timeout -1 && xperf -d C:\HighCPUUsage.etl

After you finished capturing the trace, open it by doing a double click on the ETL file. Now setup [debug symbols and load them](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh448108.aspx).

Now drag&drop the CPU usage (Sampling) graph to the analyze pane and select "utilization by Process, Stack"

[image]

Now expand the stack of your service to see which functions are called:

[image]

Microsoft [explained this here in a Video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-42-WPT-CPU-Analysis).